# Does the new Solidity version allow returning an array of struct?

Tags: solidity

All of the posts I've seen say that Solidity doesn't let you return an array struct, but when I do the following, no error is thrown and I can, in fact, get the array of struct in the front end:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

struct SomeStruct {
   string name;   
   uint number;
}

mapping(address => SomeStruct[]) database

function getAll() public view returns (SomeStruct[] memory) {
     SomeStruct[] memory structArray = database[msg.sender];
     require(structArray.length > 0, "is empty");
        
     return structArray;
}
```

Is the newer version of Solidity allowing this?

The reason I'm investigating this is because the returned array is occasionally missing an element and I can't seem to pinpoint whether this is caused by above code or not.

** Update **

```
mapping (address => File[]) database;
mapping (address => uint) public index;

struct File {
    string hashString;
    string date;
    bool isActive;
    uint index;
    uint32 size; 
    string name;   
}
    
function setFile(string memory _hashString, string memory date, uint32 _size, string memory _name) public {
    uint fileIndex = index[msg.sender];
    
    File memory newFile;
    newFile.hashString = _hashString;
    newFile.date = date;
    newFile.isActive = true;
    newFile.index = fileIndex;
    newFile.size = _size;
    newFile.name = _name;
    
    database[msg.sender].push(newFile);
    
    fileIndex ++;
    index[msg.sender] = fileIndex;
}

function getAllFiles() public view returns (File[] memory) {
    File[] memory files = database[msg.sender];
    require(files.length > 0, "There are currently no files");
    
    return files;
}
```

Comment: It should work in solidity v0.8. It was possible in previous versions using `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2`. If something doesn't work try creating reproducible example.

Comment: @Ismael I included the reproducible example. To summarize, whenever I upload an image to IPFS and get a hash value back, I'm able to upload that hash to the Ethereum network with `setFile` and download it with `getAllFiles` perfectly fine. When I upload a document like PDF to IPFS, I also get a hash value back with no issues and am able to upload it to the Ethereum network as well.  However, when I execute `getAllFiles`, only the `File` structs are fetched 100% of the time and the document `File` struct maybe 10% of the time.

Comment: The structs for PDF are simply missing from the returned array. I'm very confused about this because I know for sure that the IPFS has been uploaded properly since I get back the legitimate hash value so there's no issues there.  I also know that `setFile` is executed property because I get back the transaction details like the hash, gas price, etc with no error. When I test the above code in Truffle and Remix, there is no issue.

Comment: I tried your contract, there's no obvious issues and it works as expected. The problem might be on the client side. Perhaps there are too many files? Or some event is fired incorrectly. The solidity seems to be correct.

Comment: thanks for giving it a try. If there are too many files, such a problem could exist?

Comment: View functions are free when called off-chain but processing them has a costs in resources for the client (geth, parity, infura). Most clients set the default gas limit equal to the block gas limit (around 12M on mainnet) so if there's a lots of entries it will run out of gas. The gas limit can increased to a large amount though for view functions (I set to 100M), but returning large amounts of data can cause problems for a busy server or clients like infura.